# Xpath to locate element using text() and @class as conditions

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate adding items to cart in online shop, however, I got stuck on a loop that should differentiate whether item is available or not.

Here's the loop:

```
while True:
        #if ???
            WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='" + size.get() + "']"))).click()
            sleep(1)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Add to cart']"))).click()
            sleep(1)
            print("Success!")
            break
        else:
            driver.refresh()
            sleep(3)
```

If the size is available, button is active:

```
<div class="styles__ArticleSizeItemWrapper-sc-dt4c4z-4 eQqdpu">
    <button aria-checked="false" role="radio" class="styles__ArticleSizeButton-sc-1n1fwgw-0 jIVZOs">
        <span class="styles__StyledText-sc-cia9rt-0 styles__StyledText-sc-1n1fwgw-2 styles__ArticleSizeItemTitle-sc-1n1fwgw-3 gnSCRf cLhSqA bipwfD">XL</span>
        <span class="styles__StyledText-sc-cia9rt-0 ffGzxX">
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

If not, button is inactive:

```
<div class="styles__ArticleSizeItemWrapper-sc-dt4c4z-4 eQqdpu">
    <button disabled="" aria-checked="false" role="radio" class="styles__ArticleSizeButton-sc-1n1fwgw-0 fBeTLI">
        <span class="styles__StyledText-sc-cia9rt-0 styles__StyledText-sc-1n1fwgw-2 styles__ArticleSizeItemTitle-sc-1n1fwgw-3 gnSCRf cLhSqA bipwfD">XXL</span>
        <span class="styles__StyledText-sc-cia9rt-0 styles__StyledText-sc-1n1fwgw-2 kQJTJc cLhSqA">
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

**The question is: what should be the condition for this loop?**

I have tried something like this:

```
if (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class='styles__ArticleSizeButton-sc-1n1fwgw-0 jIVZOs') and text()='" + e2.get() + "']")):
```

**EDIT:** Replaced "=" with "," in the above code as follows:

```
if (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class='styles__ArticleSizeButton-sc-1n1fwgw-0 jIVZOs') and text()='" + e2.get() + "']")):
```

but I keep getting invalid xpath expression error.

**EDIT:** The error is gone, but the browser keeps refreshing with the else statement (element not found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using this condition:

```
if (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
 "//*[contains(@class, 'styles__ArticleSizeButton-sc-1n1fwgw-0 jIVZOs')
 and .//*[text()='" + e2.get() + "']]")):
```

It is quite similar to the original approach, however, adding `.//*` before `text()` did the trick.

Without `.//*` `find_elements` was looking in the same node which resulted in not finding the element. `.//*` instructs `find_elements` to look in the child node where element exists.

Important: text condition was wrapped in additional `[]` brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error is in the use of the `contains` function, which expects two parameters: a string and a substring, although you're passing it a boolean expression (`@class='styles__ArticleSizeButton-sc-1n1fwgw-0 jIVZOs'`).

I expect this is just a typo and you actually meant to type `contains(@class, 'styles__ArticleSizeButton-sc-1n1fwgw-0 jIVZOs')` (NB comma instead of an equals sign after `@class`).

Also, you are looking for a `button` element which has a child text node (`text()` refers to a text node) which is equal to the size you're looking for, but that text node is actually a child of a `span` which is a child of the `button`. You can compare your size to the text value of that `span`.

Try something like this:

```
"//*[contains(@class='styles__ArticleSizeButton-sc-1n1fwgw-0 jIVZOs') and span='"
+ e2.get() 
+ "']"
```

Comment: Right, that's absolutely correct!
Unfortunately, even though the error does not appear anymore, the element is not found and the browser keeps refreshing with the else statement.

Comment: OK reading it some more I see another error (your query is for a text node that's a child of the button, but in fact it's a child of a span which is a child of the button). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That was quite close. The trick was to point to ```find.elements``` that ```text()``` is in child node using ```.//*```. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Did my suggested solution not work? Incidentally, in XML terminology a "child" node is directly contained by an element; a node which is within an element but nested inside another element is called a "descendant" node (every child node also counts as a descendant node). What the `//` step is doing for you is that it's a shortcut for the `descendant-or-self` axis, whereas `/` is implicitly using the `child` axis.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not get it to work at all this way.  The only result I was getting was invalid xpath expression. Tried different variations but the outcome was always the same. This is my first project with xpath so it's very likely I was messing something up. Anyway, that was a very good suggestion as it made me look in the right place. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
e3="Some value"
x=f"//button[contains(@class,'styles__ArticleSizeButton-sc-1n1fwgw-0 jIVZOs') and not(contains(@disabled='')) and ./span[contains(text(),'{e3}')]])]"
print(x)
```

Try looking for the button which contains that class and with that span and maybe check if button disabled?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but that did not quite work as expected. I managed to fix it with a tiny addition to the original code. I added the working approach as answer.